# Need to write in excel vba to open word then do a search and replace in word. My code doesn't work when it does the search & replace in word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

```
Sub OpenWordFile()

Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
'Change the directory path and file name to the location of the document you want to open from Excel
objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Documents and Settings\CISGuest\My Documents\payroll_test1.txt"

'Search and Replace for "Prepared up to Number"
With objWord
    .Activate
        With objWord.Selection.Find
            .Text = "Prepared & Number"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindAsk
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Imagine that you were somebody else reading this question. Then imagine what kind of questions you might ask, e.g., "What do you mean by 'My code doesn't work.'?" Then include that information in your question.

Comment: You're trying to use an enumerated constant without reference to the library/late-binding.  This is causing your code (which executes without error, BTW) to perform the `wdReplaceNone` operation.  Explanation, below.

Comment: Note `wdFindAsk` is also an enumerated constant, which is meaningless when late-binding objects.

Comment: Also I don't think late binding automation supports named arguments: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/112813

Comment: @TimWilliams I think the named argument worked for me without reference to Word (I no longer have the file with code open/available to re-test). The link mentions that you can use named arguments with VB 4.0 and Excel 97, assuming they carried that forward to the current versions?

Comment: @DavidZemens - my bad - that was vbscript I had in mind

Answer (score 3):

When you use late-binding, you should use `Option Explicit` to avoid this sort of mistake.  Actually, you *should* use `Option Explicit` always.  It will identify undeclared variables and help you write better code.

`wdReplaceAll` is an enumerated constant that relies on the MS Word library reference.

When you use late-binding, it is possible that the reference is not enabled, so you can't rely on the [library-specific constant enumerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211923%28v=office.11%29.aspx) like `wdReplaceAll`.  Instead, you have to use their corresponding value, like `2`.

Change this one line:

```
.Execute Replace:=2   'wdReplaceAll
```

With late-binding, without reference to the library, and without using `Option Explicit`, `wdreplaceAll` is simply an undeclared variable which evaluates to `0`.  This value is equivalent of `wdReplaceNone` with reference enabled.

**Update**

Note: `wdFindAsk` is also an enumerated constant that means nothing unless you have the library reference enabled.  This should also be changed to `2` in your code.

Comment: I replaced wdReplaceAll with .Execute Replace:=2. But it is still not doing the search and replace.

Comment: This is why Doug and I commented above. You have provided exactly zero information about your problem that would help us, or anyone, for that matter, help you.  You're welcome, for spending some time already debugging your code. If you want any more assistance, you're going to have to provide more information: Is there an error? If so, what is the error messsage? If not, what is happening? Can you provide examples of the document? Can you provide screenshots? Can you perform the action manually (also include screenshots).  Keep in mind that we can't see your files, and we can't read your mind.

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't get any errors at all. I should explain what I'm trying to do. I am trying to put a .txt file in Excel. But before I do that, I need to clean up by doing a "Search and Replace" in Word. So I wrote a subrouting in excel. It starts with opening a file in Word. That works fine. However, when I tell it to do a search and replace in Word, it doesn't do anything at all. Is it possible for my excel vba to tell word to do anything like bold a word or select all?

Comment: Put it back in to your original question. Here's the thing: when you put it in the comments, I'm pretty much the only person who's going to see it. And I might not be able to help you.  So, when you put **ALL THE INFORMATION** in your question, that allows other people to see it and potentially help you, too.

Comment: Why don't you just us a `FileSystemObject` to open the text file, read it line-by-line, and do the `Replace` in that?  There are literally hundreds of examples of how to do this on SO, and throughout the internet.

Comment: Note `wdFindAsk` is also an enumerated constant that is meaningless when you use late-binding. You'll need to update that line of code, too, although I have no idea whether that will fix your issue.  BEcause it's such a PITA to deal with word when all you really need is to manipulate TXT, I suggest using the FSO method.  It's meant for this sort of thing.